# Config test failed when restarting apache2

Tags: 18.04, owncloud-server

I am trying to install owncloud via WSL, but there is a problem with owncloud and php versions... Now I am getting this issue:

The apache2 configtest failed. Not doing anything.
Output of config test was:

```
apache2: Syntax error on line 225 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 5 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/owncloud.conf: <IfModule takes one argument, Container for directives based on existence of specified modules
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

Comment: Please, edit your question and add your `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/owncloud.conf` configuration

Answer (score 0):

Enter into mysql:

```
sudo mysql
```

Create owncloud database:

```
mysql> CREATE DATABASE owncloud CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci;
mysql> GRANT ALL ON owncloud.* TO 'ownclouduser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'change-with-strong-password';
mysql> EXIT;
```

Install apache2, php and its modules:

```
sudo apt install apache2 libapache2-mod-php7.2 openssl php-imagick php7.2-common php7.2-curl php7.2-gd php7.2-imap php7.2-intl php7.2-json php7.2-ldap php7.2-mbstring php7.2-mysql php7.2-pgsql php-smbclient php-ssh2 php7.2-sqlite3 php7.2-xml php7.2-zip
```

Allow apache in firewall:

```
sudo ufw allow 'Apache Full'
```

Download, extract owncloud and change its folder owner:

```
wget https://download.owncloud.org/community/owncloud-10.3.2.zip -P /tmp
sudo unzip /tmp/owncloud-10.3.2.zip  -d /var/www
sudo chown -R www-data: /var/www/owncloud
```

Create owncloud.conf configuration file:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/conf-available/owncloud.conf

 Alias /owncloud "/var/www/owncloud/"

 <Directory /var/www/owncloud/>
   Options +FollowSymlinks
   AllowOverride All

  <IfModule mod_dav.c>
   Dav off
  </IfModule>

  SetEnv HOME /var/www/owncloud
  SetEnv HTTP_HOME /var/www/owncloud

 </Directory>
```

Enable the newly added configuration and all required Apache modules
 with:

```
 sudo a2enconf owncloud
 sudo a2enmod rewrite
 sudo a2enmod headers
 sudo a2enmod env
 sudo a2enmod dir
 sudo a2enmod mime
```

Reload apache2 service:

```
sudo systemctl reload apache2
```

Install ownCloud at the next address:

```
http://domain_name_or_ip_address/owncloud
```

[Reference](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-and-configure-owncloud-on-ubuntu-18-04/)

Comment: Thanks for your help..my owncloud.conf file was exactly the same as written by you, with slight indentation difference. The modules you mentioned , I had already enabled them..but when I wrote sudo a2enconf owncloud i got an error as

Comment: The error was ERROR: Conf owncloud does not exist!

Comment: I am using owncloud 10.0.10 and php 7.2.24 and ubuntu 18.04...i read that owncloud 10.0.10 is compatible with php 7.2,...but its not working in my case..also i am using a step by step tutorial...link is https://www.osradar.com/installing-owncloud-server-on-windows-10-step-by-step/

Comment: I used your references link https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-and-configure-owncloud-on-ubuntu-18-04/ and did a fresh installation...and it worked.Thank you very very much

Comment: Ok. Added the whole guide from reference to reflect your solution. Accept the answer if it helped.

Comment: Thank you once again!